# Excel VBA ThisWorkBook stopped working not sure why

Tags: excel, vba

I have recently run into an issue using "ThisWorkBook" in Excel VBA. Excel would give a "Automation error" popup and do nothing or exit the program depending on how the macro was run. I tracked the issue to the use of "ThisWorkBook" in the code

```
'This crashes
Set AccessSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ProjectAccess")
'This does not
Set AccessSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ProjectAccess")

'From the immediate window:
?ThisWorkbook.sheets("ProjectAccess").Name
ProjectAccess

?ActiveWorkbook.sheets("ProjectAccess").Name
ProjectAccess

?ThisWorkbook.Name
J073_2023_Checkbook_delete.xlsm

?ActiveWorkbook.Name
J073_2023_Checkbook_delete.xlsm
```

The workbooks are 3-4 years old, I haven't changed anything in about a year. The code in question is in a workbook that has the appropriate worksheet. This isn't the only case that crashes, just one example.

We switched to Office 365 a year or two go, I am not sure how versioning works now but I haven't noticed an update.

I am trying to understand what could have changed to make it fail? Also, why does it crash? It doesn't give a normal error or bring up the debugger, it just exits Excel without warning.

Appreciate any thoughts.

Edits:
Fixed a typo in the original code posts. Added results from immediate window

Comment: Will there be some context? Where are the variable declarations? Where is the code located? BTW, the `Book` in both, 'Active' and 'This' is in lowercase i.e. `ActiveWorkBook` looks like a variable that you have successfully assigned a workbook to. Add more detail and more cases so we can narrow down what could be happening.

Comment: ThisWorkbook refers to the workbook that has the VBA code. Does it even have a worksheet called "ProjectAccess"? ActiveWorkbook is the workbook which is active at the time.

Comment: Try putting in `Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Name, ActiveWorkbook.Name` to make sure you are actually in the workbook you think you are

Comment: I mentioned the workbook with the VBA code has a sheet with the relevent name. This happens in a few different cases with other sheet names. The code has worked for years and suddenly stopped.

Comment: I can add more context, not sure what would be useful? All of the code works, except when I use "ThisWorkbook".  I have this type of code in a sheet object as well as in a module it crashes the file in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. I have a series of Excel report programs, which have been working reliably for many years. Suddenly in October this year those which open another Excel workbook show errors similar to these. The thing they have in common is that that they work fine when run manually, but crash when run through Windows Task Scheduler. It's as though Excel can no longer work out what the ActiveWorkbook is. Sometimes the problem can be resolved by substituting ThisWorkbook, or specifically defining the currently active workbook as an object variable, at others it just leads to more rrors further through the code - eg. Sheets.Add now needs to be ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add, even though it is the only workbook open. In the end I resolved the issue by subsituting text files for the Excel reference workbooks.